# Reuse Rows Parameter ID react

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have a data table which I fetched data from firestore collection but I want to update the entries for each users in the collection. I set up a useEffect hook in the form/new component where users input data. What I'm trying to achieve is to get the ID for every specific row and show/update the data...

Here's my data table file:-

```js
const Datatable = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  // const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() =>{
// LISTEN (REALTIME)
const unsub = onSnapshot(
  collection(db, "users"),
  (snapShot) => {
    let list = [];
    snapShot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      list.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
    });
    setData(list);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);

return () => {
  unsub();
};
}, []);


  const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    try {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, "users", id));
      setData(data.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
    } catch (err) {

    }
  };


  const handleView = async (id) =>{

  }


const actionColumn = [
  
  { field: "action", headerName: "Action", width: 150, renderCell:(params)=>{
    return (
      <div className="cellAction">

        <Link to={`/users/${params.row.id}/dashboard`}>
        <Tooltip title="View Client" placement="bottom">
        <div className="viewButton" onClick={() => handleView(params.row.id)}><VisibilityIcon/></div>
        </Tooltip>
        </Link>

        <Link to={`/users/${params.row.id}`}> 
        <Tooltip title="Edit Client" placement="bottom">
        <div className="editButton"><EditNoteIcon/></div>
        </Tooltip>
        </Link>


        <Link>
        <Tooltip title="Delete Client" placement="bottom">
        <div className="deleteButton"  onClick={() => handleDelete(params.row.id)}><DeleteIcon/></div>
        </Tooltip>
        </Link>
        
      </div>
    )
  }}
]
  return (
        <div className="datatable">
            <div className="datatableTitle">
        Add New Client
        <Link to="/users/new" className="link">
          Add New
        </Link>
      </div>
      <DataGrid
        className="datagrid"
        rows={data}
        columns={userColumns.concat(actionColumn)}
        pageSize={9}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[9]}
        checkboxSelection
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Over here the "params.row.id" is showing the unique ID for each of the document in the users collection.

What I'm trying to achieve is to set that same "params.row.id" in the useEffect hook of the new component so that it fetches the exact data for each row, that is the document..

Here's my New component that hold s the formInput-

```js
const New = ({inputs, title}) => {

  const [file, setFile] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const {id} = useParams(); // over here I want to use "params.row.id" instead of fetching all the ID in the collection

  useEffect(() =>{
    // LISTEN (REALTIME)
    const unsub = onSnapshot(
      collection(db, "users"),
      (snapShot) => {
        let list = [];
        snapShot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          list.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
        });
        setData(list);
        console.log(list)
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
    
    return () => {
      unsub();
    };
    }, [id]); // over here I want to use "params.row.id" instead of fetching all the ID in the collection

    useEffect(() =>{
        if (id) { // over here I want to use "params.row.id" instead of fetching all the ID in the collection
          setData({...data[id]}) // over here I want to use "params.row.id" instead of fetching all the ID in the collection
          console.log({...data[id]})
        } else {
          setState({...initialState})
        }

        return () => {
          setState({...initialState})
        }
    }, [id, data]) // over here I want to use "params.row.id" instead of fetching all the ID in the collection


  const handleInput = (e) =>{
    const id = e.target.id;
    const value = e.target.value

    setData({...data, [id]:value});
  }

  const handleAdd = async(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Add a new document in collection "cities"
      await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
        ...data,
        timeStamp: serverTimestamp(),
      });
      navigate("/users")
  }

  return (
    <div className='new'>
    <Sidebar/>
    <div className="newContainer">
    <Navbar/>
    <div className="top">
    <h1> {title} </h1>
    </div>
    <div className="bottom">
    <div className="left">
      <img src={file ? URL.createObjectURL(file): "https://icon-library.com/images/no-image-icon/no-image-icon-0.jpg"} alt=''/>
    </div>
    <div className="right">
    
    <form onSubmit={handleAdd}>
              <div className="formInput">
                <label htmlFor="file">
                  Image: <DriveFolderUploadIcon className="icon" />
                </label>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  id="file"
                  onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
                  style={{ display: "none" }}
                />
              </div>

              {inputs.map((input) => (
                <div className="formInput" key={input.id}>
                  <label>{input.label}</label>
                  <input
                    id={input.id}
                    type={input.type}
                    placeholder={input.placeholder}
                    onChange={handleInput}
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
              <button type="submit">
                Send
              </button>
            </form>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```